# How to call a date within a gzip.open call

Tags: python, csv, gzip, glob

I am wanting to write a script where I open a gziped file with 'todays date' in its title.

Here is what I have so far:

```
todays_date = time.strftime("%Y%m%d") #format time as YYYYMMDD
nextpath = os.getcwd()
service_file = glob.glob(nextpath+"\\"+"shot_*_"+todays_date+"*_vice.gz")
input_file = glob.glob(nextpath+"\\"+"input_file.csv")

myData = gzip.open(service_file, 'rb') 
myFile = open(input_file, 'wb') with myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerows(myData)
```

This was working when I wrote the full path:

```
myData = gzip.open(D:/Temp/shot_655_20180109121455_vice.gz
myFile = open(D:/Temp/input_file.csv, 'wb') with myFile:
```

But since I have attempted to change it to make the date variable changeable I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know I am calling on it wrong somehow but I am stuck and any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're using 'with open' incorrectly. It should look like this:

```
with open(my_file, 'r') as mf:
    # do stuff here
```

this way you don't have to worry about closing it later. Otherwise you can just assign the result of open() to a variable:

```
mf = open(my_file, 'r')
....
mf.close()
```

Here's a link to the docs, with more information https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: I tried:
'code' with gzip.open(service_file, 'rb') as infile, with open(input_file, 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(infile)

But it does not work?

Comment: Could you paste your exact code with formatting, and specify exactly what doesn't work? Use https://gist.github.com or https://justpaste.it

Comment: Thanks Alex, I solved my problem with: 
for gzip_path in glob.glob(nextpath+"\\"+"shot_*_"+todays_date+"*_vice.gz"):
    if not os.path.isdir(gzip_path):
        with gzip.open(gzip_path, 'rb') as in_file, open('import_service.csv', 'wb')as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            writer.writerows(in_file)